# How can I have the keyboardlayout and system language different in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, language

Is it possible to have the keyboardlayout in one language, say german and the windows system language in another language, say english?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the two are completely independant.

I have an English Windows, and have installed four other 'keyboards' to be able to use german, spanish, and french characters as needed. The OS is still exclusively in English.

You can add any keyboards in the settings:

Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Add a Language